# (React) Easiest way to reveal on scroll?? (Scroll Fade)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, fade

I'm trying to figure out the best way to have a scroll fade in on my webpage. I tried using React Reveal however it breaks everything if you are on version 17 of React.

That being said, what would be the next easiest way to accomplish this effect?

Thanks for your time and Happy Friday!

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out the [aos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aos) npm package in which we can configure the data loading on scroll with `data-aos` attribute which has different parameters and everything is given in the npm docs linked.

Comment: Right on! I'll try this out! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Sure! do try out and comment if you have any issues